# Why am i getting error 415 when trying to retrieve database information wiht angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, post, http-status-code-415

I am learning Angular right now, and i am trying to make a POST into a API in asp.net core.
I went to the startup and made the cors since they were giving me problems. Now, my problem is an error 415, i don´t know why is saying the payload is not supported it's making 0 sense to me.
My API function is this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult register([FromBody] RegisterModel registro)
        {
            Cristais cristal = new Cristais { ID = "4", Cristal = "Zombie44" };
            _context.Cristais.Add(cristal);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            Utilizadores utilizador = new Utilizadores();
            utilizador.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            utilizador.Comida = 100;
            utilizador.Gold = 1000;
            utilizador.ID_Cristal = "4";
            utilizador.Email = registro.email;
            utilizador.NickName = registro.nickName;
            utilizador.Password = registro.password;
            _context.Utilizadores.Add(utilizador);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine(_context.Utilizadores.Where(p=> p.ID_Cristal=="4"));
            return Ok(_context.Utilizadores.ToList());
        }
```

And then i tried my post in angular:

```
registar() {
    console.log(this.utilizador);
    console.log(config.Urlsite);
    this.httpClient.post(config.Urlsite + "Utilizador/register",this.utilizador, {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'json'})} ).subscribe((resultado)=>{
        console.log(resultado);
    }, (casoErro)=>{
        console.log(casoErro);
    })
  }
```

utilizador is a variable that contains information about a user in json form something like:

{ "nickName": "Ricardo", "password": "Zombie33", "email": "aasd@hotmail.com" }

Also, registro in the API function is a model with 3 strings...

If i try this in postman it all goes well.. I dont understand why i can´t do it in angular
All help is appreciated, thanks! :)

[EDIT]
I just tried to place
[EnableCors("StratGameWebSiteAngular")]
on the API function, and than i got error 500.. i am lost right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my problem is an error 415, i don´t know why is saying the payload is not supported

In your Angular client side code, we can find that you set `{headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'json'})}`, which cause the issue.

You can set `Content-Type` with `application/json`, like below.

```
this.httpClient
  .post(
    config.Urlsite + "Utilizador/register",
    this.utilizador,
    { headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }) }
  )
  .subscribe(
    resultado => {
      console.log(resultado);
    },
    casoErro => {
      console.log(casoErro);
    }
  );
```

Test Result

[image]